# "Server unexpectedly closed network connection"

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ssh, putty

I have a raspberry Pi running Debian Jessie. All use to work fine until 3 August. Since then I have been looking for answers and trying different suggestions but to no avail.

For some reason when I come in to work in the morning I am unable to remotely access my Pi server and I’m getting the following error.

```
Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

During the day after a manual reset I can connect to my Pi server via Putty numerous times with out fail. FileZilla also connects with no problem during this time.

Then in the morning when I get to the office I try connecting via FTP with FileZilla and putty. Both give the same error. Then I go and reset the Pi server manually and all connections work. And then connection is possible from anytime of the day while I'm at work.

Then I did some research and one suggestion was that ssh times out so to fix this I added the following to the server `ClientAliveInterval 120` and to the client `ServerAliveInterval 120`. This was added in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Still does not solve the problem. I restarted ssh after I made the changes using

```
$ /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

The other thing I found is that we now possibly have to many client pi’s running from the same server and to fix that I changed `MaxStartups 10:30:60` to `MaxStartups 100`

With this problem now my scripts to update files on the Pi Clients don't run and don't update content.

With some more research I saw that one way that may help is to keep the session Alive by doing the following...

```
xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms in file etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Well, this also didn't solve the problem.

Any theory that I can try will be appreciated.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this problem ​?

Comment: You have so many SSH clients on an RPi that you had to increase `MaxStartups` to 100? Are you sure there are enough resources to support the workload?